# How to use getters to return an image in java?

Tags: java, image, getter, drawimage

I have a class which has among its attributes an Image.
I made a simple getter to return this image..

```
public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

Later I try to use this getter in a drawImage() but do not get an image.

```
g.drawImage(c.getImage(), c.getXcord(), c.getYcord(), null, this);
```

As you can see I have other getters for this class (getXcord, getYcord) which work 
fine, but I can't seem to get the image.

Here the class WoodlandCreatures

```
public class WoodlandCreatures extends Animals {
public String favPlant;

public WoodlandCreatures(String fPlant, String animal, Image im, int x, int y) {
    this.favPlant = fPlant;
    this.animalType = animal;
    this.image = im;
    this.xCord = x;
    this.yCord = y;
}
/*
public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}
      */
```

This class extends Animals

```
public abstract class Animals {
public String animalType;
public Image image; 
public int xCord;
public int yCord;


public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}
public int getXcord() {
    return xCord;
}
public int getYcord() {
    return yCord;
}
```

This is how I created the image I am using.

```
Image squir2;
BufferedImage squir1 = createImage("images/Squirrel/Squirrel1.png");

squir2 = (squir1.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
```

and here is the createImage function...

```
private BufferedImage createImage(String x){
    BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    try {

        bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(x));


        return bufferedImage;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope some of this code clears some things up.

Comment: Is `image` being initialized before you call `c.getImage()`?

Comment: Can you provide more code? The class which contains the getters?

Comment: what is `c`? did you overrided `public Image getImage()`. If yes, add @override

Comment: What is getImage() returning?

Comment: @Joe: The signature of the method is `public Image getImage()`, so it expected to return an `Image` object

Comment: @JacobT yes the image is being initialized before I call c.getImage().

Comment: heres the class woodlandcreatures

Comment: @user1804266: You might want to edit your question and post the code over there :)

Comment: @Sujay yes, it is expected to return an Image. But, it is not returning as expected. What is it returning? null? some wrong image?

Comment: @Sujay hahah yea I just did that, as you can see, I dont really know how these comments work

Comment: @Joe I believe its returning nothing, as it is not drawing the image.  I dont know another way I can test if its returning anything.

Comment: @user1804266: What about System.out.println(c.getImage()) or sth. like that?

Comment: @user1804266: How/where are you creating the image that you want to return?

Comment: @Makkes I tried the System.out.println way and it returned sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage@63238bd2

Comment: @Sujay I edited the original question to show how i make the image.

Comment: my money is on that you're try catch in createImage is stopping you from seeing an error. Are you sure it's not printing out an exception? try taking the try out and throwing the exception, or but a breakpoint on  e.printStackTrace();

Comment: @bsautner I'm a little confused about what your saying. I dont believe the error is in the making of the image, because I can just simply display the image with g.DrawImage(squir2, etc..)

Comment: Make sure you image coordinates are correct for the component you painting into, remember, the coordinates are 0x0 for the top, left corner of the component.  Also make sure that the component you are trying to paint to is actually sized

Comment: @MadProgrammer yea all of that is good, because I can actually display the image if I just use g.DrawImage(squir2, etc..) instead of g.DrawImage(c.getImage(), etc..)

Comment: @user1804266 Okay, so the image is displable, but is it being displayed within the context of the container ;)