# How to return an image

Tags: java, javafx

so basically i am creating a gameboard using **javafx** and i have a cell state class that returns a character value at the moment depending on whats in the cell. So basically if the cell is empty it returns `' '` , if i has a player in it it returns `'@'` and so on for different cell states. i was just wondering how i could return an image instead of characters.

```
public class Cell {

    CellState cellState;

    public Cell(CellState newCellState) {
        cellState = newCellState;
    }

    public CellState getCellState() {
        return cellState;
    }

    public void setCellState(CellState newCellState)
    {
        cellState = newCellState;
    }

    public char displayCellState()
    {
        return getCellStateCharacter(cellState);
    }

    public char getCellStateCharacter(CellState newCellState)
    {
        switch (newCellState)
        {
        case EMPTY:
            return ' ';
        case PLAYER:
            return '@';
        case MONSTER:
            return '&';
        case POISON:
            return '*';
        case BLOCKED:
            return '#';
        default:
            return ' ';
        }

    }


 }
```

MY CELL STATE CLASS

```
    public enum CellState
    {
    EMPTY,
    PLAYER,
    MONSTER,
    POISON,
    BLOCKED
    };



public class GameBoard {
static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 10;
static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 10;

Cell[][] boardCells;
int width;
int height;

public GameBoard()
{
    boardCells = new Cell[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];

    width = BOARD_WIDTH;
    height = BOARD_HEIGHT;
}

public void initGameBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            boardCells[j][i] = new Cell(CellState.EMPTY);
        }
    }

    boardCells[0][0].setCellState(CellState.PLAYER);

    boardCells[2][4].setCellState(CellState.MONSTER);
    boardCells[2][6].setCellState(CellState.MONSTER);

    boardCells[7][8].setCellState(CellState.POISON);

    boardCells[5][0].setCellState(CellState.BLOCKED);
    boardCells[5][1].setCellState(CellState.BLOCKED);
    boardCells[5][2].setCellState(CellState.BLOCKED);
    boardCells[5][3].setCellState(CellState.BLOCKED);

}

public String displayBoard()
{
    String output = "";
    output +="| |";
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
        output +=i + "|";
    }
    output +="\n";

    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
    {
        output +="|" + j + "|";
        for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k)
        {
            output +=boardCells[k][j].displayCellState() + "|";
        }
        output +="\n";

    }

    return output;
}
```

}

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258790/how-to-use-getters-to-return-an-image-in-java)

Comment: @user7790438 except that linked question if for an awt image and this question is about JavaFX, which has a different Image type.

Comment: @jewelsea could you give me a quick example of how i would set a cell to an image, i'm just a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

[enums are classes too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  So as the CellState enum is representing your states, probably best to encode all of the relevant info for a given state straight into the CellState class.  That would include the character and the image.

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public enum CellState {
   EMPTY(' ', "empty.png"),
   PLAYER('@', "player.png"),
   MONSTER('&', "monster.png"),
   POISON('*', "poison.png"),
   BLOCKED('#', "blocked.png");

   private final char cellChar;
   private final Image cellImage;

   CellState(char cellChar, String imageLoc) {
     this.cellChar = cellChar;
     this.image = new Image(imageLoc);
   }

   public char getChar() {
     return cellChar;
   }

   public Image getImage() {
     return cellImage;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return Character.toString(cellChar);
   }
}
```

Then you keep your cell API as before, but you can drop the `getCellStateCharacter()` method and replace its usage with `cell.getCellState().getChar()`, and similarly for image it would be `cell.getCellState().getImage()`.

To understand where the Image constructor gets the image from, see:

- [Where does javafx.scene.image.Image("flower.png") look for flower.png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575410/where-does-javafx-scene-image-imageflower-png-look-for-flower-png)

If you want to get an image from the classpath (e.g. when the image is packaged in a jar), you can use:

```
new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("player.png"))
```

The above will fetch the image from the same folder in the classpath where the CellState.class file is located.

Comment: could you give me a quick example of how i would set a cell to an image, i'm just a bit confused.

Comment: See the Square and SquareSkin classes of this [noughts and crosses game](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5115901).  That is similar to your cell concept.  It's a bit more complicated than you need but hopefully you can understand ig. Basically you need to put the ImageView in a parent node (usually a layout pane such as a StackPane or GridPane) and add the parent node to a scene.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenience i just added another part of my code to my question above. Its just that im having a hard time implementing your piece of code into mine. Would you be able to help me with this? i dont actually need the characters to be displayed, just the images

Comment: This now seems different from the original question.  The question now seems to be: "How do I creates board game grid in JavaFX?".  I think it is best to ask it as a new question.  You will likely get more and better answers that way.  You can reference this question from the new question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use byte array for image returning, and then show it on screen

Comment: Any tips on how i would go about doing that?